# select element and default option

Tags: reactjs

I have a `<select>` element and I dynamically populate the `<option>`s elements inside.
These are the stubs

```
const options = data.map((value, index) => {
  return <option key={index} value={value}>{value}</option>
});

<select
    value={this.props.selected === null ? "" : this.props.selected}
    onChange={this.props.selectHandler}>
    {options}
</select>
```

It works fine, but if the value in `this.props.selected` is `undefined`, `""`, or any value not available in the list of options, the first option is automatically selected.
This causes problems because sometimes the list of options may be refreshed and the previously selected options may not be there anymore.

Is there an easy way to make the default value for the `<select>` element to be void, forcing the user to select one the first time? I hope not to create an extra "fake" element

Comment: from where the `selected` props is coming? You can fix it there by assigning a default value `""`.

Comment: @ArupRakshit I am using redux to save the current state. In this case `this.props.selected` start with `null`, so value already is `""`, but this results in the first option being selected.

Answer (score 0):

If there's no selected value, the first value will be selected by default. You can probably prepend a non-selectable option:

```
const options = data.map((value, index) => {
  return <option key={index} value={value}>{value}</option>
});

options.unshift(<option selected disabled hidden> -- select an option -- </option>);
```

If you take a look at the fiddle, I have the first one selected, but will be hidden when expanded.

```html
<select>
    <option selected disabled hidden>-- select an option --</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
    <option value="5">Five</option>
</select>
```

Comment: thanks, this may be an option, but I was looking for something that doesn't involve adding a fake element -- assuming that it's possible, but maybe not, then this would be the only viable solution

Comment: @Naigel You have to add always an option with an empty value to get the behaviour you are looking for. This is an standard approach. `<option value="">-- select an option --</option>` is enough.

Comment: @avanthika What this attributes do there `selected disabled hidden`?

Comment: @ArupRakshit Naigel should keep it selected `this.props.selected` is null. `disabled` doesn't allow it to be selected. `hidden` hides it from list of options when the select is focused.

Comment: we have them together in there because the first option is hidden from the rest when expanded, but stays selected like a placeholder - I thought this fulfills his requirement.

Comment: In React the value props handle this, so those attributes you don't need.

Comment: I guess I implied the same :) The questioner will handle them based on the value of `this.props.selected`. I just demoed how he can do it!